# calculate average paired difference in R

Tags: r

I have a list of 1 million+ lines.

```
chr_position sick1 sick2 ... sick14 control1 control2 ... control14 p-value
chr1_1231 87.8 100 96.1 89.5 NA NA 93.8 95.7 95.5 92 NA 100 90.9 NA 100 NA 94.3 90.6 NA 92.5 100 86.7 NA NA 86.4 84.2 NA 90 0.844
chr2_412 96.1 NA 90.5 98 95.8 95.2 100 NA NA 97.5 NA 100 100 NA 100 98.5 NA 100 NA 100 100 93.6 NA 100 NA NA 93.3 NA 0.59
...
```

I wish to calculate the average paired difference of (sick1 with control1) ... (sick14 with control14) for each line.

Ideally, I would like an output of

```
chr_position pair1diff pair2diff ... pair14diff count_of_valid_pairs paired_diff
```

I realise this is an easy excel problem but due to the large row count, it isn't feasible to be performed on excel. I tried searching briefly but I don't think combn would be applicable. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are consistent and adjacent, you can just subtract them with vector math. Here's an example (i've only synthesized data for 1:4 not 1:14, but you get the idea) just change the `abs(df[,2:5]-df[,6:9])` bit to say `abs(df[,1:15]-df[,16:29])`

```
df<-data.frame(chrposition=sample(LETTERS,1000,T),
sick1=runif(1000),
sick2=runif(1000),
sick3=runif(1000),
sick4=runif(1000),
control1=runif(1000),
control2=runif(1000),
control3=runif(1000),
control4=runif(1000),
pval=0.9+(runif(1000)*0.1))


new.df<-cbind(chrposition=df$chrposition, 
              abs(df[,2:5]-df[,6:9]),   # vector diff between cols 2-5 and 6-9
              pval=df$pval)

head(new.df)

  chrposition      sick1      sick2     sick3      sick4      pval
1           O 0.21122616 0.28441462 0.4917417 0.06320374 0.9119544
2           I 0.15434718 0.07624787 0.6844081 0.19595290 0.9494703
3           A 0.03824239 0.63021683 0.2989420 0.59546995 0.9529900
4           M 0.55047434 0.11957975 0.5392134 0.05878512 0.9140963
5           H 0.20543950 0.48312551 0.1006623 0.34576621 0.9461521
6           R 0.74644532 0.12232382 0.1352527 0.67883728 0.9465176
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple in R

For instance:

```
# Generate some data
data <- matrix(rnorm(28*10000), ncol=28)
colnames(data) <- c(paste0("sick", 1:14), paste0("ctrl", 1:14))

diffs <- data[,1:14]-data[,15:28]
```

Of course, you should change the column indices depending on the structure of your data.

Comment: Thanks. That looks correct, but when I added output=c(data[,1],diffs,data[,30]) write.table(file="testingoutput.txt",output,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE,append=TRUE) for my desired output file, nothing came out.